# Installing Powerbuilder IDE 8 in win 7

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy, powerbuilder-pfc

Has anyone had success in installing Powerbuilder 8 IDE in Win 7 without any issues? Any steps to follow so that i can install in Win 7. Right now i can install but not debug or build.

**Resolved** : Installed XP mode in Win7 and in that i installed all PB related stuff and it works just fine.

Comment: What do you get? Error message, application crash?

Comment: It sounds like you have an existing project that you can't build. What happens if you make a new workspace and a simple "hello world" app?

Comment: Max, if you don't respond to the people who are trying to help you your question is going to be downvoted and/or deleted. Here's another question: Have **you** ever built this project successfully, or did you find some old 3.5" floppies in a closet?

Comment: sorry for the delay in response, I have (or had) a existing project that needed to be debugged, the migration work moved to a different vendor so didn't get a chance to look at it.

Comment: I was able to install the PB 8 IDE but there was a patch along with it which was giving some compatibility errors. would have been nice to know if it will work since the oldest version i have worked is 11.5